# MS Teams graph API meeting Attendance Report

Tags: api, graph

I tried to retrieve reports but I have an empty list but those reports already exists in the meeting chat

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#code-try-33